# Blur function on all posts

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events, meteor-blaze

The HTML code is

```
{{> addPost}}

    {{#each post}}
        {{> postItem}}

    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="postItem" >

    <div class='container'>

    <div class='col-lg-9'>
    <div class='well'>
    <span id='blur'>
    <h4><img src='{{userImage}}' class='img-responsive img-circle pull-left' height='100' width='100'/>{{name}}</h4>
    <i>Asked by {{postedBy}} on {{createdAt}}</i>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And the Javascript code is:
Here myinput is the id of the textbox where user can post.

```
'mouseover #myinput':function(event){
            event.preventDefault;
            var containerElement = document.getElementById('blur');
            containerElement.setAttribute('class', 'blur');
        },
        'mouseout #myinput':function(event){
            event.preventDefault;
            var containerElement = document.getElementById('blur');
            containerElement.setAttribute('class', null);
        }
```

And the CSS code is:

```
.blur   {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

But on hovering over the textbox with id 'myinput' the blur background only appears over the first post.Rest of the post does not show blurred background.
Please help.

Comment: `event.preventDefault` is a function.

Comment: Rectified it.Still not working.

Comment: id's must be unique. `document.getElementById('blur');` will only ever find the first element in the document with the id `blur`

Comment: @Turnip  I have used paragraph tag. <template name="postItem" >
<p>.....</p></template> and did 'mouseover #myinput':function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var containerElement = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
            containerElement.setAttribute('class', 'blur');
        },  Still it is not working.None of the post's background is getting blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('#blur')` to get all **#blur** elements, with `document.getElementById()` you get the first element with id **#blur**

or use jQuery if you want.

Comment: I have used paragraph tag. <template name="postItem" > <p>.....</p></template> and did 'mouseover #myinput':function(event){ event.preventDefault(); var containerElement = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); containerElement.setAttribute('class', 'blur'); }, Still it is not working.None of the post's background is getting blurred.

Comment: use `Array.from(container.Element).map(function(elem){ elem.setAttribute('class', 'blur'); });` to change class